# How to copy the structure of one generic type to another generic in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine we have the following input type:

```
interface Input {
    name: string;
    heightCm: number;
    dob: Date;
}
```

I would like to write a function that can produce the following output type based on this input:

```
interface Output {
    name: boolean;
    heightCm: boolean;
    dob: boolean;
}
```

In other words, a function that *copies the structure* of input and returns that structure as output, setting all values as booleans.

The function signature would look something like this:

```
interface GenericMap<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

type InputToOutput<In, Out extends GenericMap<boolean>> = (input: In) => Out;
```

If the type of the `Input` property was originally a string, mark that property as `true`, otherwise mark as `false`.

E.g. the function would produce the following result based on `Input` above:

```
{
    name: true,
    heightCm: false,
    dob: false
}
```

But most importantly, it needs to be type-safe, such that I can receive intellisense on the resulting object.

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're just looking for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) or you really want the full implementation with as strong typing as possible, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXRoDm).  Does that code meet your needs or do you want something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a mapped type that sets the type of each property to boolean?

```
type GenericMap<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: boolean
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
interface Input {
    name: string;
    heightCm: number;
    dob: Date;
}

type Output = GenericMap<Input>
// Output is
// {
//    name: boolean;
//    heightCm: boolean;
//    dob: boolean;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgWQIZgDwBUA+KAXigG8AoKGqAbQGkoV4oBrCEAewDMp8AugC4oAIy5cANhCzxKAX0qUWwZDyxpoASXhgArsArVa8LAFsIIgM7BU8AOYBuYzQAWEFPdfAAwmZHwemaiyM60UAAmXKIiACJYqs6KlKCQUADyBvqGZHCIqJg4uDrZhEA)

---

As a (potential) improvement, you could even check for `string` in this type alias and return `true` or `false`, rather than `boolean`.

```
type GenericMap<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? true : false
}
```

Which would yield this type instead:

```
type Output = GenericMap<Input>
// {
//    name: true;
//    heightCm: false;
//    dob: false;
// }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm receiving an error that the name "keyof" could not be found, when using it in GenericMap as you've shown. This works however: `type K<T> = keyof GenericMap<T>;` however I still can't use this as the key signature for GenericMap<T>. Any ideas? I'm on Typescript @4.3

Comment: The problem was that I used an `interface` to define GenericMap. It must be a `type` for 'keyof' to be used in key signature (for whatever reason)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve what you want:

```
interface Input {
    name: string;
    heightCm: number;
    dob: Date;
}

type Out<In> = { [key in keyof In]: In[key] extends string ? true : false }
type InputToOutput<In> = (input: In) => Out<In>;
type Output = Out<Input>;

const clone: InputToOutput<Input> = input => output;

const input: Input = { name: 'foo', heightCm: 3, dob: new Date };

const output: Output = clone(input);
```

Which gives the following output when hovering the `Output` type:

```
const output: {
    name: true;
    heightCm: false;
    dob: false;
}
```