# How to copy the structure of one generic type (nested object) to another generic in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

This question is very similar to a previous one I made.

I recommend reading my earlier question first: [How to copy the structure of one generic type to another generic in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105392/how-to-copy-the-structure-of-one-generic-type-to-another-generic-in-typescript)

---

Rather than cloning the structure of a flat object type, I'm looking to clone the structure of a nested object type.

In orther words, I'm looking for a function that, given...

```
// ...this input type

interface NestedInput {
  name: string;
  arr: [
    string,
    Date,
    {a: boolean}
  ];
  nestedObject: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  };
}

// ...it produces this output type

type StringMethod = (val: string) => void;
type DateMethod = (val: Date) => void;
type NumMethod = (val: number) => void;
type BoolMethod = (val: boolean) => void;

interface NestedOutput {
  name: StringMethod;
  arr: [
    StringMethod,
    DateMethod,
    {
      a: BoolMethod;
    }
  ];
  nestedObject: {
    x: NumberMethod;
    y: NumberMethod;
  }
}
```

Once again, it must be completely type-safe, such that I can access `output.nestedObject.x` or `output.arr[2].a` using intellisense.

I've been racking my brain the last 2 days trying to figure this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

PS: You may have noticed that we run into the problem of defining when we traverse a nested object. A `Date` object for instance wouldn't be traversed, but some other structure might. To prevent this from being a problem, you can assume that if the object is a vanilla JS object (see function below), then it's ok to traverse.

```
const getClass: (object: any) => string = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString);

const isVanillaObject = (obj: any) => {
    return getClass(obj) === "[object Object]";
}
```

Comment: "A Date object for instance wouldn't be traversed": My comment is not directly related to the question, but generally (IMO) Sets are better for dynamic key-value pairs. Other properties are completely separate from keys, so you wouldn't have to worry about determining whether to traverse an object, or which properties to traverse or not. With that said, Sets are not as nice to use because they don't have square-bracket notation, etc.

Comment: Your function `isVanillaObject` is runtime code and (from what I know) is not available in the type system. This function would have to be converted to a templating equivalent (which may or may not possible, I don't know)

Comment: Correction to me first comment: I meant to say `Map` instead of `Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extends` to switch on types, a mapped type for the object case and use recursion to allow deep nesting:

```
interface NestedInput {
  name: string;
  arr: [string, Date, { a: boolean }];
  nestedObject: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  };
}

type StringMethod = (val: string) => void;
type DateMethod = (val: Date) => void;
type NumMethod = (val: number) => void;
type BoolMethod = (val: boolean) => void;

type Methodify<T> = T extends string
  ? StringMethod
  : T extends Date
  ? DateMethod
  : T extends number
  ? NumMethod
  : T extends boolean
  ? BoolMethod
  : {
      [K in keyof T]: Methodify<T[K]>;
    };

type Output = Methodify<NestedInput>;

//Results in:
type Output = {
    name: StringMethod;
    arr: [StringMethod, DateMethod, {
        a: BoolMethod;
    }];
    nestedObject: {
        x: NumMethod;
        y: NumMethod;
    };
}
```

Comment: This is great! But is it possible to modify Methodify to allow traversion of arrays as well?

Comment: It already does work for tuples and arrays. If you want more control just add an `extends Array` case.

Comment: Will an array case produce a key of 'length' with a numeric value?

Comment: You would have to handle that manually. E.g. only mapping over number keys