# How to copy the structure of one generic to another generic, replacing the original values with custom values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

It may be helpful to read this question first: [How to copy the structure of one generic type to another generic in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105392/how-to-copy-the-structure-of-one-generic-type-to-another-generic-in-typescript)

Given the following input type:

```
interface InputType {
    age: number;
    surname: string;
}
```

I'd like a function that can produce the following output type for the above input:

```
type OutputValue<T> = (val: T) => void;

interface OutputType {
    age: OutputValue<number>;
    surname: OutputValue<string>;
}
```

The signature of this function would be:

```
type OutputType<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: OutputValue<T[k]>
}

type TransformationFunction<Input, Output extends OutputType<Input>> = (input: Input) => Output;
```

The type signature above will ensure that the output is type-safe. Meaning I can use intellisense to correctly retrieve the `output.surname` function (for instance).

The tricky part is returning the correct data structure in a type-safe manner.

This is my attempt:

```
const transformString = (stringValue: string) => {
    return (val: string) => {
        // some code processing val
    }
}

const transformationFunction = function<Input, Output extends GenericMap<Input>>(input: Input): Output {
    const keys = Object.keys(input) as Array<keyof Input>;

    return keys.reduce((output: Output, key: keyof Input) => {
        const inputValue = input[key];

        if (/*typeguard*/ isString(inputValue)) {
            return transformString(inputValue); // typescript compiler complains
        }
        else if ( /*typeguard*/ isNumber(inputValue)) {
            return transformNumber(inputValue); // similar function to above + typescript complains
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("No transform");
        }
    }, {} as Output)
}
```

How can I apply my custom values to the output object?

[Playground of actual problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkHIFtQIwK4EsA2ATJA7A5qAhqGgJ6Z7RIDGoASgKZ4UAuoAYgPYBOsKScHeHIqEYALPMw60KtJADdaAZ1AK20Wvg5wkjfoNAAoEIXEEFOhEwSTQAClHqAZp2iQlWbUjwpQsrwkUAlPiYaKAADhxsaBaK%20KDQUUgOSLSh8hwKSGyYBkZsDsJizApk6mgmyuaW1nhKbAiMYQ22WIVIShS1tAA0oADu6tB4YaC06UIRbGG0HIxEhmCt7oyeKABqfrF92iLBoFhNzBSqYdm0mMyi4qBiISixV8yT07NErsJE0wB0%20vpI0KdZjR6ExQA5IrAAESSBiMSEAbl%20Rjm01A2AQAjQSgAtLi8fiCYTcb9jpgzPsFABlHRYXAAXlsZg4AC5gkQAqymRTKhxaaA6QA%20UAAb30oHFoEkjCsOQA8nAAFZSRhfSaMNgo2hfdXU3k4L6dFAoGxMoJ082gSEAbTYiuVoF1tIAugj9ABfRH6Unk9oAOQQ0DgM35tl8KH8rLwmHZrLD-m5mADQY4-KFoolkto0o4OQAhH68L6bGEBApaCwUGxxDY47QAkEAGQN0D5hS%20ws1zagbGgAAMAURHqRYGw5xmlDBzg%200xxRLnRN%20WEYMwcDHU7C44EwhwACpEwgoADwAFTTYoltdZx8RGeyAGFbqPWTZMLQ%20htw7Qr2ahbI2Eg0EHX5NWBWEt0OO8TjOC4TyFBk6FhL4WDvQ8N2gcCGj3KYj1PAVgM%20ddnEggFoMYHC4JFc9xStABrfYcho2giHyUBjydVkEKYDDGGI05Xxg49aKdPC3WHejDlAY4SP4siSWyclHRwbjeNIkNi33BRWTQ7isIPQ8mVpAUf0ojMpRlWwqIzUBDwOBpLKsiV70fWg6WFGwxkYYz0wcnzxWeBQvicqNR3c2QVUYARRxVWsB3sny3VE3yM1rVz-K%20WtEp84A8IzWLRK9eTmH9QMZmUqCZLU-ytOcHSNMPRMSo4IzUxMiUzJzCzfJs7c7KSiVNTpSEGuTSE4ocoKcBctyPK8saku9ZhhQijgotZYUMrdEMPJvPqrIW0AGvHCgP3jBkSwyctK2rGKdt2iU0omkLDt5Y7Nliu6Erm5LNlcgADAASYU0oy37QGAAAqayewGST6nQUAEDLeAs2XFMnC4cQVhwSUEHuJQRBmHp4GaPoijGGYvi%20cGwEyhzsssgJ3TE0dXxe4R%20DJdGhhWbJu3nfm8TkslmAAcTHF7jw5hQufELIcgZbzxQMnBn2MxTsDK6TzkYbpLOGmZVZa4rk01vjtaZgrhfZqNpecE7aC3dVTdUhkHAQTAmDl2DO0-b8OJBRhnZk2DWvFJIWipGkcB9-x61Dqz2pyMXWcoSWbZlnnMC%20ZXsBsd6JVp0YUCR8ObD9JMZhjusgkVhOs3M5OjrTznnFl7Ivn1jg89u0BC9oYv1FrjNREiPoDrfUAAFEOEiLvIQAVUwGjMDYPock1SF8-FUT8v2igYWXNCVJkpRXfdz3shPXoWFGAAPZcQiUI-yu18iBTLzAPC8e3NNYjlWHjvtRiRBT6gHlEqJgXxgEKA-l-dYmwFBBFqKAAAgjPPARBDzAJYqeT0pl64dWgV8SQ0RpA2BsFzY%20r8tK9FfPfAA0kxWavl9oIDCOUZcaBn5awuL-G%20CsvoSkpl8ShL9eG6zulaOhjBGFEHYtbFuXB7aOzYEHbWsCVjfwQVI2gDCmJOkZr5QubpejCk2sglgjNRJAA)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your actual set-up is. Perhaps provide a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/Q) link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for-loop instead of reduce, this becomes possible:

```
(output[key] as unknown as OutputValue<string>) = transformString(inputValue)
```

Instead of `return transformString(inputValue)` which expects `OutputValue<Input[keyof Input]>`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Hx+bB4QgK1burhG1waGDMegQAwO8jO5iuxXukhe71JGIB7bl8ih1Y25qR5MxuOJqOs80DdthTMRbx-AJ5eCFifMEvlssaSvVrvlqAACws8cSzCPAFF4BYl97-CBs-OMAGFuv6ukJFIZL3DY0+eIIIx6LSd6+P8gIImCEJQmAZCqgAHuwAAsADsAA0ThgIg+jsN6e6VvQIDem4Ja-v+UDSuh+hkNh9ANvQAZAA)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Update OP with my playground also

Comment: Getting closer, but still having trouble with my playground

Comment: Ok, got it working :) Your solution works great, but it has a major flaw. Because of the weak cast to `OutputValue` there is no type safety when creating the `output` object. E.g. I can easily transform a string value into a numeric output type